# using the .split method

Tags: python, python-2.7

My question is after using the .split() method, how does python know where to start the split?

For example if I have just opened a txt file using python and I decide to use the line split method like this;

```
user = line.split(':')[0]
John: hhwoeioawn: 802:0933:Iama John:/home/John:/bin/sh
```

As you can see, the (`":"`) occurs more than once.

Comment: So what did you try and split out? You need to be a little clearer; what are you trying to *do*, what output did you expect? Did you see that there is a `str.rsplit()` method too? And that you can pass in a second argument to either method that limits how often to split?

Comment: "how does python know where to start the split": every time it sees a `:` it knows that it's probably might be a good idea to split right there and go forward.

Comment: thank you for your quick response, I am assuming that by default, the python interpreter automatically picks the first occurrence of the argument placed within the function.

Comment: Why assume when you can just try it?

Answer (score 1):

As already said, you question isn't absolutely clear. Looking at your code, it seems that you only want the first word returned by `split`, in which case, you may also use something like:

```
user = line[:line.index(":")]
```

Best regards.

Comment: No, you'd use `line.split(':', 1)` or use `line.partition(':')`; the latter is a little faster.